# Taking Array Value of JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following JSON object and want to get the value of the date. 
0.0 is "Off" status and 2.0 of "On" Status.
For my project requirement, I  want to take out as follow:

> Date ="2017-12-01" 
>   Active = 73% 
>   Off    = 26%

How can I achieve that scenario for the given JSON object?

```
{
  "2017-12-02": {
    "0.0": 1.0
  },
  "2017-12-01": {
    "2.0": 0.7379912663755459,
    "0.0": 0.26200873362445415
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you written any code yet? As much as I would like to give you the solution, it would be far better for you to demonstrate that you are willing to at least attempt to solve the problem before asking for help.

Comment: Can you please explain what you have tried?

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this:

```js
var obj = {
  "2017-12-02":{
    "0.0":1.0
  },
  "2017-12-01":{
    "2.0":0.7379912663755459,
    "0.0":0.26200873362445415
  }
}

var objectKeys = Object.keys (obj);
for (var i = 0; i < objectKeys.length; i ++) {
 var act = obj [objectKeys [i]]["2.0"];
 var off = obj [objectKeys [i]]["0.0"];
 console.log ("Date=" + objectKeys [i] + " Active=" + ((act ? act : 0) * 100).toFixed (0) + "% Off=" + ((off ? off : 0) * 100).toFixed (0) + "%");
}
```

Comment: The output is not that he want!!

Comment: @Aria add `toFixed ([precision])` to drop the fractional part

Comment: Now it works, but still have a little problem for first member of JSON

Comment: @Aria if you want to display it too than just remove `if` condition

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#map` to generate the output and `Object.keys()` to iterate through the keys.

```js
var obj = {"2017-12-02":{"0.0":1.0},"2017-12-01":{"2.0":0.7379912663755459,"0.0":0.26200873362445415}},
    result = Object.keys(obj).map(k => `Date = ${k} Active = ${Math.trunc((obj[k]["2.0"] || 0)*100)}% Off = ${Math.trunc((obj[k]["0.0"] || 0)*100)}%`);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse` to  parse the string to a JSON object(if needed), and then use it like any other object, for example use the for..in loop to iterate through dates:

```
var jso = json.Parse(str)

for (let dat in jso) {
    var out = "Date = \"" + dat + "\" ";
    jso[dat]["0.0"] && 
        (out += ("Active = " + parseInt(jso[dat]["0.0"] * 100) + "% "));
    jso[dat]["2.0"] && 
        (out += ("Off = " + parseInt(jso[dat]["2.0"] * 100) + "% "));
    console.log(out);
}
```